# Unbinding Fancybox on thumbnail fade

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using fancybox on a series of gallery images.

The user has the option to click a link which fades out certain images of a certain category.

I want to unbind the Fancybox method on the images that are faded but also re-bind when they are at full opacity.

```
$("#clientsProjects").delegate("#clientsProjects nav a", "click", function() {

    $("#clientsProjects .current").removeClass("current");

    $(this).parent().addClass("current");

    var $filterClass = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);

    $.each($filterClass, function(index, item){

        if ($filterClass != "all") {

            $("#clientsProjects .workThumbs div:not(." + $filterClass + ")").stop().fadeTo("slow", .2, function() {
                $(this).unbind("click");
            });

            $("#clientsProjects .workThumbs div." + $filterClass).stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);

        } else {

            $("#clientsProjects .workThumbs div").stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks a little crazy / long so I'm not going to bother examining it too thoroughly; however your problem seems fairly simple.

When fading an image additionally call `.unbind('click.fb')` to unbind fancybox.

And to re-apply it; the fade in methods you're using will accept a callback function that is executed on completion of the animation; within that function you can then bind fancybox onto the objects again.