# How to unbind fancybox from a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have an anchor link with a class which identifies it to be called on fancybox.
example:

```
<a class="group">some code here</a>
```

Fancybox binding:

```
$('.group').fancybox();
```

If I want to unbind fancybox with elements selected by $('.group'), how should I do that?
I have tried `removeClass('group')` but its not working.

Comment: sorry eg is like  < a class="group">

Comment: It would be possible to remove any class bound to fancybox from the anchor so fancybox won't be enabled on such anchor. The trick is how to identify the anchor in order to use the proper method. Could you clarify how do you want to remove the class: after specific event or just on page load?

Comment: Does this answer this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654085/unbinding-fancybox-on-thumbnail-fade

Comment: You might want to [check this thread][1]. It has the answer that helped me.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526599/unbind-destroy-fancybox-2-events

Comment: Doesn't this post cover the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526599/unbind-destroy-fancybox-2-events

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.group').unbind('click.fb')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add class "nofancybox" to link and this link will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in javascript code, You may select the anchor tag object and remove the class.

Give an id to the element and call the removeClass method

```
<a id="noFancy" class="group">some code here</a>
```

Java Script

```
 $(function(){
     $("#noFancy").removeClass("group");

 });
```

If you have access to the HTML markup , why not just change to class to something else but with the same CSS values. then you dont need to execute the code to remove the class on documentready

HTML

```
<a class="groupNormal">I dont want fancybox</a>
```

CSS

```
.groupNormal
{
  // Put the CSS for group class
}
```

Comment: removing class from the anchor tag in not working becoz dom collects all the elements before loading, even though i have removed the class that anchor is still being called in fancybox

Comment: Did you remove the class before binding the fancybox ?

Comment: I removed the class first thing on page load, even in page source i can see the class is removed, but it still loads the fancybox

Comment: where do you bind the fancy box method ? which event  ? documentready ?

Comment: actually that anchor is in header, and binding is done in my js file for the site,
may be if you can help me , i am goin to explain the whole prblm,

Comment: What you mean by header ? a master page ? include page ? Do you mind expanding your question including all these information ?

Comment: the link is working fine, but when we are at the same page to which link is pointing , there we have that page at two place, one the webpage and other when we click on the link same page gets loaded in fancybx, since the page contains form it is creating problems becoz we have two forms with same id and textboxes on same page,, i just want to disable fancybox at this page so that even if user clicks on that link ,that page is reloaded again, not in the fancybox

Comment: header means just a bar showing login/register links it is being included

Comment: anyways solved it using different approach, didnt needed that link on the page removed it all together showing just text

Comment: $(this).after($(this).text());
  $(this).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me, however it does not unbind the fancybox in the sense of how the questioner would like to do it.

First, don't declare the fancybox on node, but bind the node to `click` event instead:

```
$(".classOfMiniImage").on("click", window.onImageMiniClicked);
```

In the handler, you can use your code to check conditions whether you need to display the fancybox or not, and then display it with explicit `href` reference:

```
window.onImageMiniClicked = function () {
    if (<your_condition>) {
        $.fancybox({
            'href': <link_to_full_size_image>,
            /* other options below */
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'speedIn': 600,
            'speedOut': 600,
            'overlayShow': true
        });
    }
}
```

Also, you can use a bit another approach and to unbind this handler manually if you don't need the fancybox on these items anymore:

```
$(".classOfMiniImage").off("click", window.onImageMiniClicked);
```

Hope it will help someone.