# Unbind/Destroy fancybox 2 events

Tags: fancybox, destroy, fancybox-2, unbind

I am having a strange issue, I have code that pulls content via ajax and then binds Fancybox (2) to certain elements. The issue is that when I "refresh" this page I call the same function that pulls and binds Fancybox again.

My normal approach that has been working up until I changed to Fancybox 2 is to unbind the elements and rebind them. This however does not seem to be working with FB2.

I have tried the following:

```
$('.tool_button').unbind('click.fb');
$('.tool_button').unbind('click');
$('.tool_button').unbind();
$('.tool_button').off('click.fb');
$('.tool_button').off('click');
$('.tool_button').off();
```

I did notice the following in the source file which may be of use (starting line 652):

```
// Unbind the keyboard / clicking actions
    unbindEvents: function () {
        if (F.wrap && isQuery(F.wrap)) {
            F.wrap.unbind('.fb');
        }

        D.unbind('.fb');
        W.unbind('.fb');
    }
```

If anyone could help here it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Nick

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.
I created a jsFiddle to take things back to basics and try various methods. No luck so far
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/DBvt7/205/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you include the attribute `live:false` then you will be able to remove the handlers from your elements using `.off()`

After digging through the source code i've also found that the specific event is `click.fb-start`, if you want to target it specifically.

For example:

> ```
> $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({live: false});
> //remove click handler
> $('.fancybox').off("click.fb-start");
> ```

​
FYI In the documentation it says the following about `live`:

> **live:** If set to true, fancyBox uses "live" to assing click event. Set to
> "false", if you need to apply only to current collection, e.g., if
> using something like - $( "#page" ).children().filter('a').eq(0).fancybox();

## jsFiddle

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating

http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/DBvt7/211/

Comment: You should flag this as the answer. I didn't catch this until I was going to answer about the fb-start event, after digging through source code as well.

Comment: I had the same problem. Setting live: false worked for me without the need for unbinding the event.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but just wanted to confirm OAC Designs is absolutely right:
Unbinding the `.fancybox` links only works if the `live` parameter is set to `false`.

However, **you can also destroy Fancybox at the dom level**, regardless of the `live` parameter, by doing:

`$(document).unbind("click.fb-start");`

Or

`$(document).off("click.fb-start");`

---

### JSFiddle

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/gfdqen8f/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to destroy fancybox functionality on links:

```
jQuery('a').unbind('click.fb').removeData('fancybox');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, I have not tested the above, I used a different approach to resolve the issue.

What I did was instead of using the default Fancybox functionality I created functions for where I would need Fancybox and manually called Fancybox in each case which thus didn't bind the event.

This isn't the best approach and the above may be better but I will get to testing this in the new year :)

Thanks again.