# Fancybox on click event with ajax fires multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I got my desired output, but it is not best way of doing bcoz ajax is duplicating on every click.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="/messages/schedule" class="greenbtn fancybox">Schedule</a>

$('a.fancybox').click(function() {
  $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
   width : 600,
   height : 300,
   fitToView : false,
   autoSize : false,    
   type : 'ajax',
   ajax : { data : {'receiver_id' : $('#receiver_id').val(), 'subject' :  $('#subject').val(), 'body': CKEDITOR.instances.body.getData()}}
  });
});
```

First click fires one ajax request, second fires two and so on. How I can solve this?

I have also tried ready function intead of click, but ready function is not giving updated parameters which i am passing in ajax data option.

Comment: you create a fancybox for every click with the same class, and every new fancybox triggers again when clicking. remove the old fancybox before you create a new one.

Comment: unbinding it, does not give updated parameters which i am getting in ajax data section.

Comment: didnt notice you used fancybox 2, only saw it in the tags just now. i edited my answer for it, try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various solutions finally i got it resolved. Here is my code

```
 $('a.fancybox').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     type    : "POST",
     cache : false,
     url   : "/messages/schedule",
     data    : {'receiver_id' : $('#receiver_id').val(), 'subject' :  $('#subject').val(), 'body': CKEDITOR.instances.body.getData()},
     success: function(data) {
       $.fancybox(data, {
         width : 600,
         height : 300,
         fitToView : false,
         autoSize : false        
       });
     }
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<a href="/messages/schedule" class="greenbtn fancybox">Schedule</a>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getData = function() { return { data : {'receiver_id' : $('#receiver_id').val(), 'subject' :  $('#subject').val(), 'body': CKEDITOR.instances.body.getData()}}; };
  $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
   width : 600,
   height : 300,
   fitToView : false,
   autoSize : false,    
   type : 'ajax',
   ajax : getData
});
```

Comment: this does not give me updated parameters, which I am getting in ajax:{data : ""}

Comment: How about this. I did not test it though.

Comment: that does not pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for fancybox 2:

```
<a href="/messages/schedule" class="greenbtn fancybox">Schedule</a>

$('a.fancybox').click(function() {
$('a.fancybox').off("click.fb-start");
  $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
   width : 600,
   height : 300,
   fitToView : false,
   autoSize : false,    
   type : 'ajax',
   live : false,
   ajax : { data : {'receiver_id' : $('#receiver_id').val(), 'subject' :  $('#subject').val(), 'body': CKEDITOR.instances.body.getData()}}
  });
});
```

Used this answer for it:
[Unbind/Destroy fancybox 2 events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526599/unbind-destroy-fancybox-2-events)

Comment: did you notice the `live : false` parameter?

Comment: including live false does not ajax.

Comment: thats odd.. live should not change the ajax event. typo maybe?