# Remove fancybox from element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I developed a website using visual composer and also using the Easy FancyBox plugin. I'm trying to remove the fancybox from an element

```
<a class="aio-tooltip 564b7dceb3acc fancybox-vimeo" href="https://www.vimeo.com/link " target=" _blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="" title=""><div class="aio-icon" data-animation="" data-animation-delay="03" style="color:#000000;font-size:32px;margin-right:5px;">
<i class="Defaults-vimeo-square"></i>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do me a favor, and verbatim, [google your question title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669804/how-to-unbind-fancybox-from-a-selector) :)

Comment: Tried but cant figure out where should I put the script